# How to configure /public, /protected, /private access paths in Spring Oauth2 Security

Tags: spring-security

I have a very specific requirement in my project related to identity & authorization. I want to open 3 paths `/public/`, `/protected/` & `/private/` from my REST service module, which will behave as follows:

1. URLs starting with `/public/` can be accessed without any authentication or authorization.
2. URLs starting with `/private/` can be accessed only if the user is authenticated.
3. URLs starting with `/protected/` can be accessed only if the user is authenticated as well as authorized.

To achieve this I have built a `Configurator` by extending "spring resource server configurator & overriding the `configure` method". But unfortunately it's not working.  I have also tried to use "spring web service configurator & using the ignore ant url support " but the same is also not working. The configuration which is working only for `/private/` & `/protected/` URLs is as follows.

```
http.anonymous()
    .disable()
    .requestMatchers()
    .antMatchers("/protected/**", "/private/**")
    .and();

for (String protectedApiEp : configuredApis) {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/protected/" + protectedApiEp + "/**")
        .hasAuthority(protectedApiEp);
}

http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/protected/**").denyAll()
    .antMatchers("/private/**").permitAll()
    .and()
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

Can anyone guide me how I can enable `/public/` URLs as open to all users, with the above configuration?

Comment: Which type of security ? simple spring security or spring oauth?/

Comment: Why do you add `.anonymous().disable()` (you wrote, that you want anonymous access to `public`) and `.antMatchers("/protected/**", "/private/**")` (overrides your other lines).

Answer (score 2):

The following configuration should work:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebApplicationSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // Allow Spring Security to authorize requests.
    http
        .authorizeRequests()

            // Allow anyone to access URLs starting with /public/.
            .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()

            // Allow anyone with the protected role to access URLs starting with /protected/.
            .antMatchers("/protected/**").hasAuthority("protected")

            // Allow anyone who is authenticated successfully to access all other URLs.
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/48180378) is a sample application that shows this configuration in action. Start the application as `mvn clean spring-boot:run` and then navigate to [`http://localhost:8080`](http://localhost:8080) to access the application.